# How to verify if mouse is clicked over a SDL Surface?

Tags: algorithm, events, sdl, mouse

How could I verify if mouse was clicked over the `gimage_1` area coordinates?

The `gScreenSurface` is the main surface where `gimage_1` is drawn.

Basically I am stuck how to get the `gimage_1` coordinates and verify with mouse clicked position.

Pseudocode:

```
    SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;  
    SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *gimage_1 = NULL;
    SDL_Event e;

     while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
     {
            switch (e.type) {
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    int x, y;
                    SDL_GetMouseState( &x, &y);
     }
     SDL_BlitSurface( gimage_1, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );
     SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SDL_Surface` objects are images without position or area. You give them a position when you render them onto the screen via a `SDL_Rect`. In your example, `gimage_1` does not have any coordinates. The `SDL_Rect` you use when rendering it does.

Comment: Did not figure how to give specified position to them. I used `SDL_BlitSurface( gimage_1, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );` to draw them.

Comment: Managed the positions with `SDL_Rect`!